# Is there a way to ping(mention) mods when ticket bot sends a message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to ping mods or admins when ticket bot sends a message?
My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="+")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")

ticket = ["915745817694961664"]

@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    for word in ticket:
        if word in msg.content:
            await ctx.send("Someone created a ticket! @Mods @Admins")

client.run("TOKEN")
```

I dont know if this is possible, but I hope there is way to do this

Answer (score 3):

You need to use role id like this:

```
if word in msg.content:
            await ctx.send("Someone created a ticket! <@&883807051548065833> <@&876611793227755550>")
```

> To get the ID of a role, enable developer mode
> in the Appearance section of your user settings, then go to the role
> menu in the server settings and right click on the role you want the
> ID of, then click "Copy ID".